# rails 4 - using has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two types of data: `Team` and `Game`. A team can belong to more than one game (eg. a college can play basketball, football, and soccer), and each game naturally has many teams that play in the league.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
end
```

There's a table in the db with two columns to hold these relationships:

```
create_table "games_teams", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "game_id"
  t.integer "team_id"
end
```

So far so good.

I need to build a form to add new `Teams` but I can't get the `Game` to show up correctly:

```
<%= form_for @team, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal form', :role => 'form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:game_id, Game.all, :id, :name) %>
```

This throws an error `undefined method game_id for #<Team:0x007fa1af68f2d8>`

How do I properly insert `game_id` when working with a `Team` object, and `team_id` when adding a `Game`? I realize these ought to handle a "multi-select" scenario, but at the moment I can't get any of it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a `Commodity`? Are you sure that @team have teams, and Game.all return the games?

Comment: @fotanus-- sorry, typo-- 'commodity' is the name in the error, I changed the name of the actual data to make it more obvious what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is to use `game_ids[]` instead:

```
#View
<%= f.collection_select(:game_ids, Game.all, :id, :name) %>

#Controller
def create
   @team = Team.new(Team_params)
   @team.save
end

private

def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(game_ids: [])
end
```

This should set the collection values for `has_and_belongs_to_many` data. I'll have to test this when I get into the office - it definitely works, but whether the syntax is right is what I've got to find

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter on `collection_select` is an attribute from the object that is been described. So, this line

f.collection_select(:game_id, Game.all, :id, :name)

Try to call `game_id` on the object `team`, which fails.

I'm not sure if there is a direct method supported by rails to help you construct this associations. You can always construct a solution with [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) and [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) (with `mutiple: true` since it is a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, send an array of game_ids to your action and deal with it manualy.

You might also take a look on this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast)

Answer (score -1):

Try using association instead of collection_select

```
<%= form_for @team, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal form', :role => 'form'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :game, collection: Game.all.map{|p| [p.id, p.name]}, :label => 'Drive', :prompt => "Select Game" %>
```

Comment: @anusha-- this returned `undefined method association for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fb06bddd308>`

Comment: oh, actually i have used this association input wit simple form but here your using form_for.Please try this using "simple_form_for" simple_form gem. check this link for reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: @anusha-- I'd prefer to do it with plain rails first, so I can understand what it's doing before I install more gems that obscure how it's really working. Thanks though!

Answer (score -2):

I believe you want to use has_many through instead of has_and_belongs_to_many. like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_teams
  has_many :teams, :through => :game_teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_teams
  has_many :games, :through => :game_teams
end
```

Comment: what are the different between two?

Comment: looks like they are the same. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: @MikeS-- I will give that a try, though I believe that the `through` is used when the middle table has its own model-- otherwise the `has_and_belongs_to_many` is used.